# Need a button at the bottom of a Relative Layout in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-button

I am very new to Android. I am creating an application with clickable text in it.
All the clickable text is present in an array which is then associated with a `ListView` and displayed inside the RelativeLayout.

Code for it is -

```
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, R.id.label, contact_name));
    ListView lv = getListView();
```

main is the relative layout, label is the text box id inside the layout and contact_name is the array that goes as the clickable text. This is all working fine.

Finally when the array is very large, linear layout becomes scrollable.

Now I want to restrict the area occupied by this list to 80% or 90% of the total screen height and reserve the space at the bottom for a button which will open a new page/view. Including the button inside relative layout is adding a button to every item in the list. Changing the height of the relative layout is changing height of each item in the list. This concludes that each item in the array is associate with the whole relative layout and an array of relative layout comes for displaying all the items. Now How do I put a button at the bottom by restricting the relative layout list to 80% of the screen from the top.

This is how the current XML file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Next"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_above="@id/btn">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

End of code

The output is an array of Next buttons with the actual contents hidden.

This is my Java Code

```
// Make the contact number parameter accessible to member functions of List View
        final String[] f_contact_number = contact_number;

        // Binding Array to ListAdapter
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, R.id.label, contact_name));

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // listening to single list item on click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {

              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
              intent.setData(Uri.parse(f_contact_number[position]));
              startActivity(intent);

          }
        });
```

Contact_number and contact_names are two string arrays which calls a number on clicking the contact_name

```
Thanks
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Next"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_above="@id/btn">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Scroll view content"
            >
        </TextView>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So the button will stick to bottom of parent and remaining space will be occupied by `ScrollView`
Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this but somehow the buttons are appearing as a list. The number of Next buttons is equal to the number of elements in the array. There isn't a single Next button at the bottom as desired. More over the actual text in the array is not visible and is not clickable either. Probably each of the Next button is lying over those texts and hiding them

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the xml file, please? @user2550128

Comment: Your xml gives proper o/p in my emulator. What do u do in java file to load text in scrollview? @user2550128

Comment: Can you check the code and tell me what is wrong? I am getting a series of Next Buttons with no contact being displayed.

Answer (score 2):

This is easier to do using `RelativeLayout`. If you want to do this using `LinearLayout`, you can set **layout_height** of the views to **0dp** and use **layout_weight** to distribute the height

Comment: Can you please check the code and tell me what is wrong that I am doing?? I tried a lot but the output that I get is not desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/yourbtnid"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="your text" >
    </TextView>
  </ScrollView>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/yourbtnid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This code and the code suggested by Rapunzel are essentially the same. Please take a look at the output which is created. It is some thing like                                                             Button
Button
Button
Button arranged vertically with the actual elements not being visible

Answer (score 0):

I did what Anamika suggested, and it worked like a charm.

I changed a code a bit, so the button is set in the middle, and not filling up all the space.

Maybe your problem is in the java code, not in the layout code.

Did you getting it to work?

Please let me know if you're still struggling, I have have a look at it and help you resolve.